# Не подключается база данных H2

Tags: maven, jdbc, h2

Не могу подключиться к базе данных H2. Использую IDEA, Maven. Выдает следующую ошибку
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.h2.Driver

Вот код:

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class Util {

```
private final static String DB_DRIVER = "org.h2.Driver";                           
private final static String DB_URL = "jdbc:h2:~/test";                             
private final static String DB_USERNAME ="sa";                                     
private final static String DB_PASSWORD = "";                                      

public Connection getConnection(){                                                 
    Connection connection = null;                                                  
    try {                                                                          
        Class.forName(DB_DRIVER);                                                  
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);
        System.out.println("Connection OK");                                       
    }catch(SQLException e){                                                        
        e.printStackTrace();                                                       
        System.out.println("Connection ERROR");                                    
    }                                                                              
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e){                                              
        e.printStackTrace();                                                       
        System.out.println("Connection ERROR");                                    
    }                                                                              
    return connection;                                                             
}                                                                                  

public static void main(String[] args) {                                           
    Util util = new Util();                                                        
    util.getConnection();                                                          
}
```

}

файл pop.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.jdbc.tutorial</groupId>
<artifactId>jdbc-tutorial</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.h2database/h2 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.196</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас scope вашего JDBC драйвера ограничен:

> < scope >test< /scope >

Уберите эту строку из maven dependency и попробуйте снова

Comment: Теперь друга ошибка Database may be already in use: null. Possible solutions: close all other connection(s); use the server mode [90020-196]

Comment: Проверьте, не открыта ли она у вас где-то еще? Может в браузере в админке вы подконнектились?

Comment: Спасибо, все закрыл, перезагрузился и - работает